# Why is std::is_base_of<T, T> true when T is a class type, but false when T is a built-in type?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, type-traits

Per [meta.rel] (20.10.6 in C++14), for a class type `T`, `std::is_base_of<T,T>` is true, but for a built-in type `T`, `std::is_base_of<T,T>` is false. Colloquially speaking, class types are bases of themselves, but built-in types are not. What is the motivation/utility for this difference in treatment?

Answer (score 23):

The rationale goes back quite a ways, and is not well documented.

`is_base_of` was originally called `is_base_and_derived`, and was introduced in TR1.  Dave Abrahams introduced an issue against this class in [N1541](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2003/n1541.pdf), number 3.13:

> Currently, `is_base_and_derived<X,Y>` returns false when `X` and `Y`
>   are the same. This is technically correct (`X` isn’t its own base
>   class), but it isn’t useful. The definition should be loosened to
>   return true when `X` and `Y` are the same, even when the type isn’t
>   actually a class.

Unfortunately the issue does not expound on why that definition is not useful.  However the viewpoint was not unique at the time (2003).  [Andrei Alexandrescu's Modern C++ Design](http://erdani.com/index.php/books/modern-c-design/) published two years earlier had much the same trait, and much the same comment in section 2.7 about its macro `SUPERSUBCLASS`, though this book also added a workaround macro if you really didn't want a class to be considered its own base.

[Modern C++ Design](http://erdani.com/index.php/books/modern-c-design/) goes on to use `SUPERSUBCLASS` in section 3.12 to order a Typelist in order of inheritance.  Deep in the details of this exercise, the fact that `SUPERSUBCLASS(T, T)` is true is taken advantage of (for convenience in the implementation).

By 2004, the [TR1 report, N1647](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2004/n1647.pdf), had adopted the notion that `std::is_base_of<T,T>::value == true` was useful when `T` is a non-union class type.

[N2255](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2255.html) further clarifies how `is_base_of` is supposed to work for non-class types, and this change resulted in the wording that you see today.  However there are extensive editorial differences between what this accepted paper proposes, and what was produced in the following draft ([N2284](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2284.pdf)).  My opinion is that the editor greatly improved the wording.

The undocumented rationale for why [N2255](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2255.html) created a division between non-union class types and everything else is that `is_base_of` historically answered questions about the inheritance hierarchy of types, with only a convenient "trick" that a class can be considered its own base via the "is-a" analysis.  However types that can't possibly participate in an inheritance relationship *should never* qualify as base classes, according to the multiple authors of this trait.

Whether or not that was the best design is up for debate.  However there are sufficient traits (e.g. `is_class` and `is_same`) to build whatever you need from these fundamental traits.

This is more of a history, rather than a straight-forward "why".  However the point of this answer is to call out that `is_base_of` evolved over a great deal of time, through many iterations.  And each iteration was felt at the time to be an evolutionary improvement upon what was there before.

And it all boils down to: This is the spec that the committee thought would be most useful.  But as the spec & design evolved over many years, and through several authors, there exists no good overall design document or rationale.

Comment: You can't write `class Foo : int {};` for any `Foo`.  So even though an `int` is-a `int` You still can't have a hierarchy involving and `int`.  Hmmm.  (Aside, this might be a nice way to write opaque typedefs).

Answer (score 2):

Built-in types are not classes, and things that aren't classes cannot be a base of *anything*.

If anything I'm somewhat surprised that `std::is_base_of<T,T>` is true even for class types, but that's probably a "can be treated as a" relation for classes.

Meh, I dunno.

Comment: If you need `T` to be of a given type, or derived from it, `std::is_base_of` expresses it correctly. If it was not reflexive, you would almost always have to use it with `std::is_same`. Also, most systems with subtypes use reflexivity.

Comment: @DanielKO: As things are now, I suspect that in some cases, you'll have to use `std::is_fundamental` prior to applying `std::is_base_of` in order to deal with the fact that fundamental and class types are treated differently by `std::is_base_of`. What's not clear is what that asymmetry buys you.

Comment: @DanielKO: Yet for some types _it doesn't_.